# PHP - unknowable echo <<< construct

Tags: php, echo

I have this construct found in a PHP script: `echo <<<Start;` in the script.

What does that mean?

My assumption is that's a kind of redirection, but it's only an assumption and I want to know the real function of this construct.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc Its a way of having multiline strings, called heredoc syntax

Answer (score 1):

It is called `heredoc` syntax:

```
echo <<<END
This uses the "here document" syntax to output
multiple lines with $variable interpolation. Note
that the here document terminator must appear on a
line with just a semicolon. no extra whitespace!
END;
```

Comment: Examples is from http://php.net/manual/en/function.echo.php